# Averaging the difference between multiple values in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a tab delimited text file with 2 columns, Bill to Name and Date, date is in Excel number format.  The code...

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict( list )

input_file = "C:\\Users\\Intern\\Documents\\Python.txt"
output_file = "C:\\Users\\Intern\\Documents\\b.csv"

with open( input_file, 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader, None)  # skip the header
    for row in reader:
        d[ row[0] ].append( int(row[1]) )

with open( output_file, 'w' ) as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    for key, value in d.items():
    if len(value) == 1:
        avg_diff = None # or 0 -- this indicates there was only 1 purchase
    else:
    # This requires your dates to be sorted, ascending, but that just takes
    # wrapping 'value' in 'sorted' if it isn't sorted yet
        avg_diff = mean([v[i] - v[i-1] for i, v in enumerate(value) if i])
    writer.writerow( [key, avg_diff] )
```

Current error:

`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1e819db94549> in <module>()
     22         # This requires your dates to be sorted, ascending, but that just takes
     23         # wrapping 'value' in 'sorted' if it isn't sorted yet
---> 24             avg_diff = mean([v[i] - v[i-1] for i, v in enumerate(value) if i])
     25         writer.writerow( [key, avg_diff] )`

`<ipython-input-2-1e819db94549> in <listcomp>(.0)
     22         # This requires your dates to be sorted, ascending, but that just takes
     23         # wrapping 'value' in 'sorted' if it isn't sorted yet
---> 24             avg_diff = mean([v[i] - v[i-1] for i, v in enumerate(value) if i])
     25         writer.writerow( [key, avg_diff] )`

`TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`

This is what I'm running into now with the updated code.

Comment: So do you need mean value of all days for each key?

Comment: I need the mean value of the differences in values for each key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `max(value) - min(value)`, it seems (if I understand correctly) that you could write:

```
def mean(x):
    return float(sum(x))/len(x)

...
for key, value in d.items():
    if len(value) == 1:
        avg_diff = None # or 0 -- this indicates there was only 1 purchase
    else:
        # This requires your dates to be sorted, ascending
        sv = sorted(value)
        avg_diff = mean([sv[i] - sv[i-1] for i in range(len(sv)) if i])
    writer.writerow( [key, avg_diff] )
```

This will give you the average between-date length, for each person.

I would think `None` is better for single-purchasers, because 0 is a valid value when two things were purchased on the same day.

Comment: I re-titled it.  I was midway through typing a question about an indexing error when I had an enlightened moment and fixed it, and when I went to enter a new question for this, stackoverflow kept what I had previously typed.  That was my mistake, sorry.

Comment: How can I protect against dividing by 0 with this?  Some differences are 0.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if a difference is zero, so long as there is at least one difference, because the only thing dividing anything is the number of differences (length of the difference vector). Sorry I didn't include that case -- I'll do it now.

Comment: To give some needed context (didn't realize it would be needed, sorry), the dates I have are purchase dates for customers.  The 0's are important to have in the list because they denote customers that only made 1 purchase, but I'd like to know what the average time between purchases was for customers who made multiple purchases.  There shouldn't be any empty lists, so I'm not sure where the 0 is coming from.

Comment: If the dates are only dates, and not time-stamps, then wouldn't any two purchases made on the same day have the same date? Resulting in a difference of zero? I've incorporated this in to my answer.

Comment: Yeah I think my problem right now is the wrapping 'value' in 'sorted' part. I don't think I'm doing that right.

Comment: writer.writerow( [key, avg_diff] )  Changed avg to avg_diff first because avg was undefined, now I am getting "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" pointed at line "avg_diff = mean([v[i] - v[i-1] for i, v in enumerate(value) if i])"

Comment: Yikes, that was really dumb of me -- should be fixed now.

Comment: Totally! Apologies for the rushed mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need a simple function to calculate the average.

```
def avg(iterable):
  count = 0
  running_sum = 0
  for item in iterable:
     running_sum += item
     count += 1
  return running_sum / float(count)
```

Now you just need the values.  If I understand your intent, you want the values at `i` minus the values at `i - 1`...

[`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) has a recipe to do almost this, though it shouldn't be hard to write your own without itertools if you want:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

We didn't get the difference, but that's easy to do in a generator which we can pass to our `avg` function (since we were careful to make `avg` work with *any* iterable, not just sequences):

```
average = avg(n - p for p, n in pairwise(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your other post, this code should fix it.  It'll take all the dates per name and associate them with that name as a sublist.   Then, it sorts the sublist to get the dates in order and finally writes the AVERAGE between the biggest and smallest dates.  The averaging would be best done in it's own function, but I kept it simple(er).

```
import csv
index = []
input_file = 'input.csv'
output_file = 'output.csv'

def find_name(index, name):
    """ Binary search to see if the name exist in the index, yet. """
    if len(index) == 0:
        return -1
    start = 0
    limit = len(index) - 1
    while start <= limit:
        guess = (start + limit) / 2
        if index[guess][0] == name:
            return guess
        elif index[guess][0] < name:
            start = guess + 1
        else:
            limit = guess - 1
    return -1

def add_to_index(index, name, date):
    """ sorts the existing index.   Sends the variables to "find_name".
        if the name is round, returns the address of the name in the list.
        if it's not found, it returns a -1. """
    index.sort()
    name_index = find_name(index, name)
    if name_index == -1:
        index.append([name, [date]])
    else:
        index[name_index][1].append(date)


""" Read throught each row of the input file, skipping the header. 
    send each row to the "add_to_index" function."""
with open( input_file, 'rb' ) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader, None)  # skip the header
    for row in reader:
        add_to_index(index, row[0], row[1])

""" Write the output from the index back to the output file, only
    showing writing the earliest date for each user. """
with open( output_file, 'wb' ) as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    for e in index:
        print e
        name = e[0]
        if len(e[1]) == 1:  #if only one dates, answer is 0
            average_days = 0
        elif len(e[1]) == 2:  #if only two dates, answer is the diff
            e[1].sort()
            average_days = int(e[1][-1]) - int(e[1][0])
        else:  #if more than two dates, average.
            e[1].sort()
            total = 0
            total_dates = len(e[1])
            print total_dates
            count = len(e[1]) - 1
            while count > 0:
                total += int(e[1][count]) - int(e[1][count - 1])
                print total
                count -= 1
            average_days = total / total_dates
        writer.writerow([name, average_days])
```

I made a new input file to get more than two dates.  It looks like this:

```
Bill to Name    Date
James Doe       41929
Jane Doe        41852
Adam Adamson    42244
Adam Adamson    41529
Adam Adamson    41852
```

The output looks like this:

```
Adam Adamson    238
James Doe       0
Jane Doe        0
```

Comment: I have the difference between largest and smallest, what I'm looking for now would be the average difference between all dates.  If they have dates W, X, Y, Z, then I want the average of the difference between W and X, X and Y, and Y and Z.

Comment: That's the beauty of doing the data structure the way that I have.... it makes changing the output easy.  One sec....  I'll give you an example.

Comment: I updated it.  The only difference is the last chunk of code.